# Remove the square brackets in ieee-alphabetic style for the bibliography with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, ieee-style

I have the square brackets in the JOURNALS, on the left. I just want to get rid of the square brackets, but keep what is inside [here, Aut01, Aut02 and so on] for the bibliography only.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}




  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage{spanish}
\setotherlanguage{german}

%\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,   citetracker=true, citestyle=alphabetic, bibstyle=ieee-alphabetic, sorting=ynt,sortcites=true]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{testcite.bib} 


\usepackage{filecontents} \begin{filecontents}{testcite.bib}
@book{a01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@book{a02,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@article{c01,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
@article{c02,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Charlie},
}

@article{c03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {1978},
  title = {Charlie},
}
@article{c04,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {1981},
  title = {Charlie},
}

@article{ac01,
  author = {Cuthor, C. and Author, A.},
  year = {1987},
  title = {Charlie},
}
@article{ac02,
  author = {Cuthor, C. and Author, A.},
  year = {1973},
  title = {Charlie},
}

@article{ac03,
  author = {Cuthor, C. and Author, A.},
  year = {1981},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}



\begin{document}
Refs. \cite{a01, a02, ac01, ac02, c01, c02, c03, c04, ac03}

\today

%\clearpage


\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
\selectlanguage{german}
\printbibliography[ heading=subbibliography,title={Journals}]
\endrefcontext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the citation labels in the bibliography is controlled by the `labelalphawidth` and `shorthandwidth` formats (for numeric labels there is also `labelnumberwidth`).

So

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{#1}
```

should do it.

In the citations the brackets are either hard-coded (as is often the case in the `textcite` macros) or given by the wrapper command supplied to `\DeclareCiteCommand`. Changing those brackets can require more code even though it is not actually more difficult.